# C# is httpRuntime cache data stored on the hard disk?

Tags: c#, httpruntime

Or how to set up let him save to the hard disk don't let him work in `memorySystem.Runtime.Caching`  `MemoryCache` if work in memory

Comment: Really not sure what are you asking?

Comment: Is httpRuntime cahce data is stored in the hard disk？

Comment: NO, it's stored in the process memory

Comment: I remember I had a teacher like me is to turn off the demo program can also be taken to re-open the cache , or if I remember correctly , which is in the hard disk category provides a Microsoft .NET Framework